# Cygwin Awk Split file into multiple files and saving with proper file names

Tags: awk, split

I have searched enough and nothing works for me. Its been 2 days now and I have to ask this question. I am using Awk with Cygwin. My data looks like this

```
Center Name,Account Number,Client Status
2001 - LA Center,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxx
2001 - LA Center,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxx
3005 - SD Center,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxx
3005 - SD Center,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxx
```

As you can guess, I am trying to separate this file into multiple files based on the center name which is the first column.It would be also nice to copy the headers to each file. Expected output:

```
Center Name,Account Number,Client Status
2001 - LA Center,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxx
2001 - LA Center,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxx

Center Name,Account Number,Client Status
3005 - SD Center,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxx
3005 - SD Center,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxx
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is:

```
awk -F, '{print > $1}' file
```

or if you want to replace all spaces with underscores in the file names:

```
awk -F, '{f=$1; gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"_",f); print > f}' file
```

If you aren't using GNU awk then you might need to close() the output files as you go to avoid a "too many open files" error. You are on cygwin and so already using gawk so that's not an issue for you, just for others who may read this and aren't using gawk (get gawk!).

Oh, and if you want a header line duplicated in all output files this might do it (untested):

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{h=$0 ORS} {print h $0 > $1; h=""}' file
```

or maybe this, also untested due to no input/output to test against:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{h=$0; next} !seen[$1]++{print h > $1} {print > $1}' file
```

---

The OP had control characters in his input file, here's how to clean them up with `awk` (and why not to try it with `tr`):

```
$ cat file
abc
def

$ cat -v file
a^@b^@c^M
d^@e^@f^M

$ tr -d '[:cntrl:]' < file | cat -v
abcdef$

$ awk '{gsub(/[[:cntrl:]]/,"")}1' file | cat -v
abc
def
```